# How can i sum pay_price value in group footer

Tags: jasper-reports

How can I sum `pay_price` value in group footer:

```
<variable name="total" class="java.lang.Integer" calculation="Sum">
    <variableExpression><![CDATA[$F{pay_price}]]></variableExpression>
</variable>
```

but its suming all value-s.

[image]

Comment: Java? This doesn't look like Java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding the resetGroup

```
<variable name="total" class="java.lang.Integer" resetType="Group" resetGroup="myGroup" calculation="Sum">
    <variableExpression><![CDATA[$F{pay_price}]]></variableExpression>
</variable>
```